# Time series data manipulation

Tags: r, time-series, data-manipulation

I've had this problem before, but I didn't write down the solution, so now I'm in trouble again!

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
Date    Product    Qty    Income
201001  0001       1000   2000
201002  0001       1500   3000
201003  0001       1200   2400
.
.
201001  0002       3500   2000
201002  0002       3200   1900
201003  0002       3100   1850
```

In words, I have one line for each combination of Date/Product, and the information of Quantity and Income for each combination.

I want to rearrange this dataframe so it looks like the following:

```
Date    Qty.0001    Income.0001   Qty.0002    Income.0002
201001  1000        2000          3500        2000
201002  1500        3000          3200        1900
201003  1200        2400          3100        1850
```

In words, I want to have one line for each date, and one column for each combination of Product/Information(Qty, Income).

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `reshape`:

```
reshape(x,idvar="Date",timevar="Product",direction="wide")
    Date Qty.0001 Income.0001 Qty.0002 Income.0002
1 201001     1000        2000     3500        2000
2 201002     1500        3000     3200        1900
3 201003     1200        2400     3100        1850
```

Comment: Awsome! I was trying to use `cast` and `melt` functions from `reshape` package without success. This is much simpler and completes the task!